# preserve intra-word asterisks while removing the rest

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to remove all `-`, `'`, `*` from a string except those that are inside a word, using `gsub` in R, but am having problems with the intra-word asterisks.

For example, this sentence: `a* dash-- 'can't see intra-word-hyphen f**eb**k'` should become `a dash can't see intra-word-hyphen f**eb**k`. (Give or take some extra whitespace, which doesn't matter.) All other punctuation marks have already been removed in a previous step.

The regex I have right now can preserve intra-word hyphens and apostrophes, but not asterisks, and I can't figure out why.

```
gsub("(\\w['*-]\\w)|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", x)
```

This produces: `a dash can't see intra-word-hyphen febk`

When I try to escape the asterisk, like so:

```
gsub("(\\w['\\*-]\\w)|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", x)
```

It still gives the same output.

How can I get R to recognize the asterisk inside the `[ ]` as a literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in this case you simply forgot to allow for multiple asterisks:

```
x <- "a* dash-- 'can't see intra-word-hyphen f**eb**k'"
gsub("(\\w['*-]*\\w)|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", x)
# [1] "a dash can't see intra-word-hyphen f**eb**k"
```

In general, to escape `*` you would need `\\*`.